# Can I add tags to an existing question?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And if so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9054/can-i-add-tags-to-an-existing-question?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like retagging of questions is covered here: http://answers.ros.org/faq . Seems we need 500 karma to retag questions.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-15**:
I've lowered the retagging threshold to 100 to make it easier as we get this forum started.